# Convert View Based application to NavigationBased

Tags: iphone, ipad, view, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am new to iPhone development.

I created simple `ViewBased` Application in which, i have 2 pages `Licpage` and `PlanPage`
i have set `LicPage` as my RootViewController in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`,

Now when i click on button in `LicPage` i will navigated to `PlanPage` but in my `PlanPage`
i am unable to see my NavigationBar with back button on it.

**Note:** I can't drag NavigationBar manually with back button on it. because when i will add 3rd page, it will also navigate to 2nd page(`PlanPage`). and when i will click on back button it will take me on firstpage(`LicPage`) not in third page.

Comment: What do you mean by because when i will add 3rd page, it will also navigate to 2nd page(PlanPage)?And can you explain your navigation?

Comment: on 2nd page i have written this code on back button `- (IBAction)Back:(id)sender {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];
}` but what if if i visit 2nd page from 3rd page and when i click on back button it should navigate me to 3rd page na, but it will navigate me to first page because of my code above.

Comment: No if you are going to 2nd page from 3rd page it will not take to 1st page when you call dismissModalViewController because dismissModalViewController will just dismiss the view it will not navigate.And one more thing you should not declare your viewcontroller as rootviewcontroller in AppDelegate.Do as Ishu has suggested.

Comment: chk http://www.mediafire.com/?7x5bb0naeca0ilc

Comment: Can you post your screen shot?

Comment: there is no navigation bar on second page http://i.imgur.com/0CxPe.png

Comment: On first page you are able to see navigation bar?How you are pushing your second page?Can post the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{ 
   self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease]; 

self.viewController = [[[LicAppViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LicAppViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease]; 

UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
 [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES; 
}
```

Comment: On first page you are able to see navigation bar?How you are pushing your second page?Can post the code?

Comment: i am able to see navigation bar on first page, there is a btn on first page on click of btw i am navigating to new 2nd page,here is code,`-(void)PlanbtnClicked{
        
    PlanPage *_planViewController = [[PlanPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlanPage" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
   [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:_planViewController animated:TRUE];
    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:_planViewController animated:TRUE];
    [_planViewController release];
}
`and code in finish launching method is same as you suggested above.

Comment: when you are mentioning it is not visible you should have mention that it is not visible on second page.Otherwise how others will know where it is not visible.You should not use presentModalViewController instead you should push your viewController as follows:SecondViewController *viewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];

Comment: sorry for inconvenience, Thnax for the help it working properly with pushviewcontroller as you suggested, but as per requirement i have to use `presentModalViewController`. if you can help me then it is well and good

Comment: What is your requirement, why you have to use presentModalViewController only?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12734/discussion-between-nuzhat-zari-and-krunal)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make NavigationController in appDelegate class (delete viewController rootViewController).

And use this in .h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

in .m

```
@synthesize navigationController
```

and make object of LicPage (objLicPage) and set as rootviewcontroller for navigation controller

```
self.navigationController.rootViewController = objLicPage;

[self.window addSubView:navigationController.view];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: i deleted this lines as you said `UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_viewController];
    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];`  and when i writes your code it shows me property `rootViewController` not found

Comment: the code before when you suggested, `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    self.viewController = [[[LicAppViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LicAppViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];    UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_viewController];
    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}`

Comment: after i wrote `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    
    self.viewController = [[[LicAppViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LicAppViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.navigationController.rootViewController = _viewController;
    [self.windownavigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
`

Comment: I am unable to open your link.Please check my reply.Hope it solves your problem, it works fine for me.